# How to delete any string beginning with a backslash?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file containing much TeX mark-up, like this:

```
The fish ate 20\percent more food than the bear.
The fish ate \the\number\percent more food than the bear.
```

I want to delete that text which is a TeX code, like `\percent` and replace it with a space.

- The mark-up always begins with a `\`.
- The mark-up always is followed by a space, `{`, or another `\`.
- The `\` is never used in other situations in the file.

How can I delete the appearance of these items, which begin with `\` and afterwards are followed by a space, `{`, or another `\`?

Comment: It sure looks like it's followed by a space...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this perl command:

```
perl -pe 's#\\[^ \\{]+# #g' file.txt
```

OR using sed:

```
sed -E 's#\\[^ \\{]+# #g' file.txt
```

OR if -E is not supported then:

```
sed -r 's#\\[^ \\{]+# #g' file.txt
```

#### OUTPUT

```
The fish ate 20  more food than the bear.
The fish ate     more food than the bear.
```

Comment: +1 If you want to replace sequences of markup with a single space: `sed -r 's#(\\[^ \\{]+)+# #g'`